# Access denied when editing a page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, permissions, publishing-site

I have a Sharepoint publishing site and I am controlling permissions using custom permission levels.

I have created a permission level for editors and one for approvers.  They have all of the necessary permissions to be able to edit pages and lists.  (The only difference between an editor and an approver is that the approver can approve).

I have granted those permissions levels to two AD groups, one for editors and one for approvers.

I have also made sure that all authenticated users have read access to the master page gallery and style library.

Still, every time I log in as a user that is a member of a group that has been granted the editor permissions level they see the access denied screen when trying to edit a page.

I have tried googling this one for hours but the answer always seems to be to make sure that the user has read access to the master pages gallery - in this case they do.

Does anyone have any idea of what else this could be?

Jim

Answer (score 1):

Check that all elements that contribute to the page are saved, checked in, published as a major version (and approved, if approval is required). That goes for

- Master Page
- Page Layouts
- custom CSS
- custom scripts
- anything else in the Style Library or the asset libraries, etc.

Comment: Hi Teylyn,Thanks for that but ive checked and everything is checked in, published and approved.  Still no joy.

Comment: What about item level permissions? Is the list set up so that users can only edit the items they created, maybe? -- What about permission levels. Can you post screenshots of the custom permissions you created? Why would you create your own permission levels and not use the out of the box levels?